# Fixed order with limited set, then resume normal order

Tags: templating, elementcriteriamodel

I have a news page (/news). You can open an article (i.e. /news/test-article) which uses the same listing template, but has an accordion open with content for that article (javascript/push state magic).

In the event someone goes directly to /news/{slug} I want to make sure that article is the top one in the list.

Is it possible to go i.e.

```
$criterea = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criterea->section = 'news';
$criterea->order = 'postDate desc';
$criterea->ids = [$startArticle->id, {magically fall back to default sorting!}];
$criterea->fixedOrder = true;
```

Or am I going to have to futz with the array manually after the search?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `news/test-article` just an example of `news/{slug}`? And is this for a plugin (hence the PHP) or a template (hence the templating tag for your question)?

Perhaps what you want to do is start by grabbing the slug from the URL and getting the entry you're after:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('news').slug(craft.request.lastSegment).first %}
// output
```

Use that to display the first entry, then get the rest of the news entries but filter out the active:

```
{% set otherEntries = craft.entries.section('news').id('not ' ~ entry.id) %}
{% for otherEntry in otherEntries %}
    // output
{% endfor %}
```